# populating data on parent window or some other window after submiting data in popup window using spring

Tags: spring-mvc

my requirement is that i want to populate data on parent jsp or might be in some other jsp as on closing of pop up using spring. The problem i faced i m able to open pop but after submitting the value the data is populated on same pop up i want that on differnt page ,for example what i have done as the popup open i  have submit the value  of 'Employee_Id` the data is populated on popup itself i dont know how to populate data on different page   using spring here is my code

this is my controller

```
package com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeForm;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.EmployeeBO;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchEmployeeController {

    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;

    public void setEmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl) {
        this.employeeServiceImpl = employeeServiceImpl;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchspring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String view() throws Exception {
        return "Home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView search(@Validated EmployeeForm employeeForm,
            @RequestParam("selectedValue") String selectedValue)
            throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        if (selectedValue.equals("FindEmployeeById")) {
            boolean x = true;
            model.addObject("x", x);
        }
        if (selectedValue.equals("FindEmployeeByName")) {

            boolean y = true;
            model.addObject("y", y);

        }

        if (selectedValue.equals("FindByDepartmentId")) {
            boolean z = true;
            model.addObject("z", z);
        }
        model.setViewName("Search");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/FindById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView searchByEmpNo(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm)
            throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        Integer i = (employeeForm.getEmployeeNumber());

        EmployeeBO employeeBO = employeeServiceImpl.getEmployee(i);
        System.out.println(employeeBO);
        model.addObject("employeeBO", employeeBO);
        model.addObject("block", "block");

        model.setViewName("EmployeeDetail");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/FindByName", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchByEmployeeName(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        List<EmployeeBO> employeeBOs = employeeServiceImpl
                .findEmployees(employeeForm.getFirstName());
        model.addObject("listEmployeeBO", employeeBOs);
        model.addObject("block", "block");
        model.setViewName("EmployeeList");
        return model;

    }
```

and this is my jsp page

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<fmt:setBundle basename="ApplicationResources" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Search Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doAllThese(url) {

        if (url == 'FindById') {
            document.form.action = "/EmployeeWebSpring/search/FindById";

        }
        if (url == 'FindByName') {
            document.form.action = "/EmployeeWebSpring/search/FindByName";
        }
        if (url == 'FindByDeptNO') {
            document.form.action = "/EmployeeWebSpring/search/FindByDeptNO";
        }
    }
    function loadName(name) {

        this.firstName = name;
        window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/EmployeeWeb/GetEmployee?key1='
                + encodeURIComponent(firstName);

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form name="form" commandName="employeeForm" method="post">



        <c:if test="${requestScope.x}">
            <div id="div1">
                Employee_ID:
                <form:input path="employeeNumber" />
                <input type="submit" name="method" value="FindById" id="FindById"
                    onclick="doAllThese(this.value)" />
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${requestScope.y}">

            <div id="div2" >

                Employee_Name
                <form:input path="firstName" />
                <input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByName"
                    onclick="doAllThese(this.value)" /> <br /> <font size=3>For
                    Searching the employees by<b>Employee Name</b><br />you can use %
                    match all the records with the given pattern
                </font><br /> <font size="2"> <i>e.g <b> for search by</b>EmployeeName<br />
                        matches alL the employees whose name starts with character <b>S</b></i></font>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${requestScope.z}">
            <div id="div3">
                Employee_Name
                <form:input path="departmentId" />
                <input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByDeptNO"
                    onclick="doAllThese(this.value)" />
            </div>
        </c:if>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my ds-servlet xml in which i m using internal view resolver

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="driverClassName" />
        <property value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.25.30:3306/employee"
            name="url" />
        <property value="hr" name="username" />
        <property value="hr123" name="password" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="employeeDaoImpl" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.dao.impl.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeserviceImpl" class=" com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl">
        <property name="daoImpl" ref="employeeDaoImpl" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mycontroller"
        class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers.SearchEmployeeController">
        <property name="employeeServiceImpl" ref="employeserviceImpl"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="emplController" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers.EmployeeController">
        <property name="employeeServiceImpl" ref="employeserviceImpl"></property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="configurationLoader"
        class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader" />
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator"
        p:configurationLoader-ref="configurationLoader" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="com/nousinfo/resources/messages" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, here are your options:

1. Submit the popup, store the relavent updated data in session or somewhere you can get to it, then using JS call a reload on the parent page
2. Make the loading of the parent table AJAX, then after the popup dismisses, recall the AJAX code to reload the contents of the page.
3. Come up with some really complex JS to update the parent page using the data on the popup...I think this is not a good solution

Spring MVC is a server-side tool, meaning all the data is being processed on the server's side.  If you want to pick up any new data using Spring directly, you will need to make a call to the server one way or another.